# TypeScript compilation error TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided

Tags: compiler-construction, typescript

Cannot compile any TS+node.js project including listed in samples http://typescript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#samples/imageboard/README.txt

Always get the following error:

error TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

compiler's version: 0.9.1.0

For example, the project consists of just  single file app.ts:

---

```
///<reference path="./node_definitions/node.d.ts" /

import http = require("http")

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:1337/');
```

---

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned compile with the module flag, e.g. if your file is called `myfile.ts` :

```
tsc myfile.ts --module "commonjs"
```

The reason is that starting from TSC 0.9.1 the default module option is amd (e.g. requirejs) which is the most common module pattern for client side javascript code. So, you need to specify the module option to get commonjs code which is the most common module pattern for server side javascript code (e.g. nodejs) which is why the compiler is prompting you to be explicit about your target :) This prompt occurs when you do an `import` on an external module.

Answer (score 29):

Also just to add.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 I got this same error running build to fix it.  I went to the properties of my project and then to the "TypeScript Build" section in there was the option to pick a module system I selected AMD it was at none.

Comment: I also had "None" and this worked perfect, thank you. One more thing I want to add though is you can still can a different error if you haven't let Typescript know of your external module. Something like this: `declare module 'angular' {
    var angular: ng.IAngularStatic;
    export = angular;
}`

Comment: I've done this and I still get the error. Starting to wonder if it's a VS2015 bug, now.

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar issue with the GraphQL samples, where I had used create-react-app myapp --typescript.

TS1208

[image: GraphQL compiler error]

Was able to fix it like this:

[image]